# How to pass Azure authentication(MSAL OpenID Connect tokens) created for a ASP.NET web site passed along to MVC applications accessed from the website

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal

My Website in IIS set to **https://MyTestWebsite** ([Image of MyTestWebsite website in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYFqw.png))

MyTestWebsite (ASP.NET 4.5 framework) uses Azure authentication (MSAL implicit grant flow)  ([Image of Sign in for Azure authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjvoD.png))

A MVC5 application - Testapplication is added to website in IIS under MyTestWebsite **https://MyTestWebsite/TestApplication** ([Image of TestApplication under website in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jQNX.png))

Run the website. Click on My Test Application (it's a link in website) when redirect how to pass the azure authentication from MyTestWebsite to TestApplication ( [Image of Click on application from website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Zsy.png))

Need answers how to pass azure authentication from ASP.NET website to MVC applications added to the website

Comment: consider formatting the question. the images are not visible and all text is bold for some reason.

Comment: Can see now i formatted it should be good

Comment: i think new users have to wait a day before adding images and making them visible. right now, its still not visible :)

Comment: I didn't know about this, thanks for info

Comment: I rephrased little bit in an hope may be without image you can understand

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD supports [single sign on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on): a user doesn't have to sign in to every application they use. The user logs in once and that credential is used for other apps too. It's just a matter of setting [Azure AD authentication in your MVC application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/vs-active-directory-dotnet-getting-started).

Comment: That means if I have to set authentication for the MVC application, is it by using the same application id used by the website for azure authentication or new application id (new app registration for MVC application) ? –

Comment: @SamSubbiah It can be a new app id.

Comment: In that case I have more than 4 applications connected with the portal website. Since I'm using OpenID Connect MSAL with id token. Is the token per tenant or application,  wondering how to manage tokens for all these applications if its per app id.

Comment: @SamSubbiah id tokens are issued per tenant, app and user. What do you mean with manage?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response very useful. Sorry let me rephrase my question how do i manage session. All these 4 applications are connected to portal website now use windows authentication and session is shared among applications started from website. How do i replicate the same thing now with azure now replaced windows authentication.

Comment: @SamSubbiah AAD session with be shared trough a cookie so you will be able to select any currently signedin account.